# Wireless not working on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wireless

Just installed ubuntu 14.04 on my Compaq Presario V2069CL Notebook PC, The wireless does not work. What is the command to install the wireless driver?
The Broadcom model is BCM4318 (using lspci -vvnn | grep 14e4).

Comment: Take a look at the "Additional Driver" (`software-properties-gtk --open-tab=4`) or follow this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install firmware for `b43` driver.

Connect to internet by wire and run:

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

Comment: If you can't connect to internet by wire, I will give a guide how to install the firmware offline.